# Proving uniform continuity using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definitions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I've written some proofs. Can someone please verify them?

> 1) Prove that $f(x) = \displaystyle{\frac{1}{x}}$ is uniformly continuous on $\displaystyle{\left[\frac{1}{2}, \infty\right)}$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Set $\displaystyle{\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{4}}$.

Suppose $x, y \in \displaystyle{\left[\frac{1}{2}, \infty\right)}$, with $|y-x| < \delta$.

Then, $|f(y) - f(x)| = \displaystyle{\left|\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{x}\right| = \frac{|y-x|}{|xy|} \leq 4|y-x| = 4 \delta = \epsilon}$

> 2) Prove that $f(x) = \displaystyle{\frac{x}{x+1}}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, 2]$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Set $\delta = \epsilon$.

Suppose $x, y \in [0,2]$, with $|y-x|<\delta$

Then, $|f(y) - f(x)| = \displaystyle{\left|\frac{y}{y+1}-\frac{x}{x+1}\right| = \frac{|y-x|}{|y+1||x+1|} \leq |y-x| < \delta = \epsilon}$

> 3) Prove that $\displaystyle{f(x) = \frac{5x}{2x-1}}$ is uniformly continuous on $[1, \infty)$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Fix $\delta = \displaystyle{\frac{\epsilon}{5}}$.

Suppose $x, y \in [1, \infty)$, with $|y-x|<\delta$.

Then, $|f(y)-f(x)| = \displaystyle{\left|\frac{5y}{2y-1} - \frac{5x}{2x-1}\right|} = \frac{5|y-x|}{|2y-1||2x-1|} \leq 5|y-x| < \epsilon$

Comment: Looks okay to me.  Nice job using the lower bounds properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these all look fine, however, I had to stop and think why certain inequalities were true which is usually an indication that they aren't necessarily obvious. For example, in question $3$ I think you should explain why

$$\frac{5|y-x|}{|2y-1||2x-1|} \leq 5|y-x|.$$

More precisely, why $|2y - 1||2x - 1| \geq 1$ (of course, it is enough to explain why $|2x - 1| \geq 1$). Likewise, I think you should explain why $|xy| \geq \frac{1}{4}$ in question $1$ and why $|y+1||x+1| \geq 1$ in question $2$.

Just to re-empahise, your arguments are completely correct; the above comments are based only on my opinion of what requires explanation, and may differ from someone else's opinion.

Comment: Your second inequality should be reversed.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Thanks.